# How to disable change value in ngModel

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I've got component of  in Angular 5 - trying to build unit-test which check when it's disabled than impossible to set value to model of component.
And I don't know why - it's still possible to change.

```
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  [attr.disabled]="disabled ? 'disabled' : null"
```

and test looks like this - and it's gave me error

```
    it("DISABLED", async(() => {
    component.disabled = true;
    component.value = 'testtesttest';      
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const htmlInputComponent: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const inputValue = htmlInputComponent.querySelector('input').value;
    expect(inputValue).toBeFalsy();
}));
```

Tried to add some rules in ngOnChange - but it still makes changes in value.

Comment: I am not familiar with this unit testing, but shouldn't `textareaValue` be `inputValue`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan sorry - little mistake - changed it.

Comment: You can try with `[disabled]="disabled"` instead of `[attr.disabled]="disabled ? 'disabled' : null"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
[attr.disabled]="disabled ? true : null"
```

Comment: There is a difference between `[attr.disabled]="disabled ? true : null"` and `[attr.disabled]="disabled ? 'disabled' : null"`. Agree? The later will not set `attr.disabled` to true but to striing `disabled`. So when you do `component.disabled = true;`, it sets the value of `disabled` to true but value of attr.disabled will be `disabled` and not `true`.